# In a formula, refer to a sheet by a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

First post, and very very newbie on VBA. I work out my problems but doing copy/paste from examples on such fine forums and sites like this one.

Here's my problem:

Current worksheet is CAPA, and cell D2 has a value (181 for example).

The value on cell D2, which is 181, is also the name of another worksheet I already created.

On my VBA code, working on sheet CAPA, I want the macro to write this formula on cell B12:

```
='181'!B9
```

and I want it to pick up the 181 from the value on cell D2

I already tried this:

```
Dim MySheet As String, ws As Worksheet
MySheet = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D2").Value
Set ws = Sheets(MySheet)
```

and then

```
Range("B12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='ws'!B9"
```

But instead, it opened a dialog to point a file containing the ws reference.

Would be deeply thankful to any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said cell `B2` but in `VBA` code you mention `D2`. So, correct this line `MySheet = Sheets("CAPA").Range("D2").Value` with `MySheet = Sheets("CAPA").Range("B2").Value`

Comment: Done. Thank you :-)

Comment: If you found answer useful then mark it as accepted (Tick as green).

Comment: I'm so sorry, it returned an error. I commented about the error on the answer u gave :-)

Comment: Corrected. My mistake, it was D2 all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you do not need to set worksheet. Just you need to pass sheet name to formula. Try following sub.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim MySheet As String
    MySheet = Sheets("CAPA").Range("B2").Value

    Range("B12").Formula = "='" & MySheet & "'!B9"
End Sub
```

Comment: It returned: runtime error '1004' - application defined or object-defined error on the "Range("B12").Formula... line.

Comment: It will return error when sheet name does not exist. Sheet name means value in `B2` cell is a sheet name.

Comment: I have checked it out found the code working. What is value in `B2` cell in sheet `CAPA`?

Comment: Where the sub is written and how it is triggered. Please trying `Sheets("CAPA").Range("B12").Formula = "='" & MySheet & "'!B9"`

Comment: Damn!! It was D2 all the way from the beggining! IT WORKED!!! :-D Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

try giving everything names in vba, i find this easier to follow. also use cell reference in easier when you get used to it (row,column). below code should work:

```
  Option Explicit

  Sub hh()
       'declare workbook
        Dim bk As Workbook

        'give capa and the workshhet you want use names
        Dim capa As Worksheet
        Dim cellSheet As Worksheet

        Dim MySheet As String

        'set the woorkbook
        Set bk = ThisWorkbook
        'set capa
        Set capa = bk.Worksheets("CAPA")

        'set the myString variable to b2 (same as row 2, column 2)
        MySheet = capa.Cells(2, 2) 'b2

        'set the sheet as the value of the string
        Set cellSheet = bk.Worksheets(MySheet)

        'with the sheets set values are easily exchanged:
        capa.Cells(12, 2) = cellSheet.Cells(9, 2)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Set cellSheet = bk.Worksheets(MySheet) returns Runtime error '9' subscript out of range

Comment: yea, Sub hh() 'declare workbook Dim bk As Workbook sould be code

Comment: Set cellSheet = bk.Worksheets(MySheet)
will depend on if there's a valid sheet name in the cell of CAPA 2,2